# Ubuntu Touch on Sony Xperia M2

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu on my device, but when I run:

```
sudo ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

I get this back:

```
2015/06/28 23:13:09 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/06/28 23:13:09 Device is |D2302|
Device D2302 not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
```

How I can install Ubuntu on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the handset is supported first. Having a quick look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices this device does not seem to be supported.

Comment: I think there is a big difference if you use the driver from the android. And the same developers are testing Ubuntu on their phones.